# Closed points in the fiber over a closed point

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I have a simple question: if $f: X\to Y$ is a morphism of schemes and $y\in Y$ is a closed point, can I deduce that a point $x$ in the fiber $X_y$ is closed in $X$ if I know that the residue fields $k(x),k(y)$ are finite? I was thinking about the formula $0 = \operatorname{tr.deg}(k(x)) = \dim \overline{\{ x\}}$ but this only seems to work for schemes (of finite type ?) over a field. Could we apply this to $X_y$ as a scheme over $k(y)$?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!
Since the fiber $X_y$ is closed in $X$ it is enough to prove that $x$ is closed in the scheme $X_y$.
But for any scheme $Z$,  I **claim**  that any point $z\in Z$ whose residue field $k(z)$ is finite must be  a closed point.
So in our case $x$ will indeed be closed in $X_y$.

**Proof of claim**
 Since being closed is a local property (general topology!) we may assume that $Z=\operatorname {Spec} R$ and that $z$ corresponds to the prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subset R$.
Then the inclusion $R/\mathfrak p\subset k(\mathfrak p)=\operatorname {Frac}(R/\mathfrak p)$ forces $R/\mathfrak p$ to be a field since it is a finite domain.
Hence $\mathfrak p$ is maximal and $z$ is closed, as promised.

Comment: thank you, nice proof! Is the answer to my last question also positive? Is the formula valid for $X_y$?

Comment: You are welcome. In your formula  $0 = \operatorname{tr.deg}(k(x)) = \dim \overline{\{ x\}}$, over what field do you take transcendence degree ?

Comment: Over k(y), I also know that $X_y$ is of finite type over $k(y)$. The formula uses actually the transcendence degrees of the function fields.

Comment: Yes, if $X_y$ is of finite type over $k(y)$, it is true that $tr.deg_{k(y)} (k(x)=\dim\overline {\{x\}}$ : this is a consequence of Noether's normalization theorem.

Comment: it may be relevant to note that a point is closed if it is closed in all affine opens, generally speaking checking if the point is closed in only one dense affine open is not enough.